# Excel - Check if column has specific text

Tags: excel

I went to [this site](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text). It says the answer is this:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,text))
```

I need it to check a column so I tried:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C5,B5:B25))
```

but of course this doesn't work.

I also tried [another article from the same site](https://exceljet.net/formula/value-exists-in-a-range), but I have no idea how to present the range.

Comment: So you want it to return TRUE, if the value in C5 is anywhere in B5:B25?

Comment: Do you want to match on part of the cell or the whole cell?

Comment: It would really help if you mocked up some data and expected output.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. It would return TRUE, if the value in C5 is anywhere in B5:B25. It should behave like the example in https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text      ----however this example shows a formula that checks if the value in one cell is located in the adjacent cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MATCH instead of SEARCH()

MATCH whole cell:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5,B5:B25,0))
```

MATCH part of cell:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&C5&"*",B5:B25,0))
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Craner. I'm not getting the result I desired. Does the formula only work with numbers ? I just get 0 as the answer. In my scenario. Column 5 has substring "Cow-Parachute-Training" and there's a match somewhere in B5:B25 that says something to the effect of "YellowFever-Cow-Parachute-Training-2008".

Comment: Then you need to use the second formula.  And you should get True/False not 0.

Comment: Thanks for Craner. I adjusted my data to work with your 1st iteration of the solution. I appreciate your help.